# How can I show the text with different fonts in textView in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am doing one application. In that I need to show text in different fonts. I mean if I show name in one font and I show city name in different font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];

textView.text = @"Vijay Apple Dev";

NSString *textViewText = textView.text;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textViewText];

[attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:20]
                       range:[textViewText rangeOfString:@"Apple"]];


[attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20]
                       range:[textViewText rangeOfString:@"Vijay"]];

textView.attributedText = attributedText;

[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to do like this one...  And customize according to your requirement like font name and font size

```
        NSString *firstName = @"FirstName";

        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:firstName];

        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20];

        [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, firstName.length)];// Here define your range.

        textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Use attributed String

//Apply properties to both strings 

//then merge and set it to textview

NSString *selectedString=@"Hey,";  

UIFont *fontSelectedText = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25];

NSDictionary *dictBoldSelectedText = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontSelectedText, NSFontAttributeName, nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewSelectedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:selectedString];

[mutAttrTextViewSelectedString setAttributes:dictBoldSelectedText range:NSMakeRange(0,selectedString.length)];

[_tTextView setAttributedText:mutAttrTextViewSelectedString];


//Second String
NSString *restOfStrig=@"\nHello";
NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:restOfStrig];

UIFont *fontText = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
NSDictionary *dictBoldText = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontText, NSFontAttributeName, nil];

[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:NSMakeRange(0,restOfStrig.length)];

//Combining both the Attributed String
[mutAttrTextViewSelectedString appendAttributedString:mutAttrTextViewString];

NSMutableAttributedString * finalAttributedStr=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:mutAttrTextViewSelectedString];

//setting it to the textView
[_tTextView setAttributedText:finalAttributedStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSAttributedString`

> An NSAttributedString object manages character strings and associated sets of attributes (for example, font and kerning) that apply to individual characters or ranges of characters in the string. An association of characters and their attributes is called an attributed string. The cluster’s two public classes, NSAttributedString and NSMutableAttributedString, declare the programmatic interface for read-only attributed strings and modifiable attributed strings, respectively.

[NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

When you create your attributed string, then just set it to your textView:
`self.textView.attributedText = myAttributedString;`